# Removing extra line in recaptcha in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, recaptcha

I can't seem to remove that exta line at the bottom in my recaptcha, I tried to removed all my css and its still there. What seems to be my problem?

[image]

Comment: Show your code as well.

Comment: You could try `#recaptcha_area, #recaptcha_table { line-height: 0!important;}`

Comment: @chridam I'll just put it in my css? Will it conflict in the plugin?

Comment: Cheers, will put that as an answer if you find it helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
#recaptcha_area, #recaptcha_table{ 
   line-height: 0!important;
}

#recaptcha_area input {
   height: auto;
   display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Quick question: When I press `enter` instead of the button for the recaptcha it won't read what I type in the textarea whether if its correct or not.

Comment: You can enable the Enter key on recaptcha by wrapping the recaptcha control and the Button in a Panel control. Then set the DefaultButton property of the Panel control to the ID of your button. More details [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1509970.aspx?Enabling+Enter+Key+with+reCaptcha).